# change code to select more classes in javascript

Tags: javascript

Look at this piece of code:

```
<script src="progressbar.js"></script>

<script>
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(containera, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
  text: {
    style: {
      // Text color.
      // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
      color: '#999',
      position: 'absolute',
      right: '0',
      top: '30px',
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      transform: null
    },
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: {color: '#FFEA82'},
  to: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
  step: (state, bar) => {
    bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 40));
  }
});

bar.animate(1.0); 
</script>
```

The above code selects element with class "containera" and does something with them. I want change my code so it will select bellow classes too:
containerb,containerc,containerd,containere,containerf
but I don't like to repeat my code for every class. I hope you help me :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you wrap your configuration in a function and call it for every container you have? Could work along those lines:

```
var yourContainers = ['containerA','containerB']

function createProgressbars = function(container){
 return new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
  text: {
    style: {
      // Text color.
      // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
      color: '#999',
      position: 'absolute',
      right: '0',
      top: '30px',
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      transform: null
    },
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: {color: '#FFEA82'},
  to: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
  step: (state, bar) => {
    bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 40));
  }
});
}

yourContainers.forEach(function(container){
  createProgressbars(container).animate(1.0);
});
```